# Continuous motion is a myth and the speed of light is a convention

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, conventions, identical-particles

Suppose that we have two particles, $A$ and $B$, which are identical in all respects except for their positions, and position-dependent properties (velocity, momentum, etc.) At some point in time, which we'll call "$0$," the positions (or position probability densities, it doesn't actually matter) of $A$ and $B$ are $\mathbf a_0$ and $\mathbf b_0$, respectively.

We take out our infinite-precision stopwatch, and begin our observations. Over the course of one second, the particles trace out two continuous paths, which we can represent as the vector valued functions $\mathbf a,\mathbf b:[0,1]\to\Bbb R^3$ (or $\psi_A,\psi_B:[0,1]\to(\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb C)$, again, it doesn't matter) with $\mathbf a(0)=\mathbf a_0$ and $\mathbf b(0)=\mathbf b_0$ (or $\psi_A(0)=\gamma\ \delta^3(\mathbf x-\mathbf a_0)$, where $|\gamma|=1$, and... you get the point.)

I claim the following:

---

If $E$ is any subset of $[0,1]$, and $\mathbf s_A,\mathbf s_B$ are the functions given by

$$\mathbf s_A(t)=\begin{cases} \mathbf a(t) & t\in E\\
\mathbf b(t) & t\in [0,1]\setminus E\end{cases}\qquad\mathbf s_B(t)=\begin{cases}\mathbf b(t)&t\in E\\ \mathbf a(t) &t\in [0,1]\setminus E\end{cases}$$

then the positions of particles $A$ and $B$ at time $t$ are given by $\mathbf s_A(t)$ and $\mathbf s_B(t)$, respectively. In other words, at any time after $0$, $A$ and $B$ may instantly and simultaneously teleport to each others' locations.

---

I ask that someone refute this claim.

Comment: The title seems to be unrelated to the body of your post.

Comment: @Sandejo The first part of the title is because the idea of "continuous motion" is predicated on coherent notion of "identity," which cannot exist if we have many indistinguishable things. The second part is an allusion to the fact that certain obvious truths in physics - i.e. "the speed of light is constant and equal in all directions" - are a matter of convention, just as it seems "each particle in a set of indistinguishable particles travels along a unique, continuous path" might be. I think people are taking it much more seriously than intended.

Answer (score 3):

Your title doesn't seem to suggest "continuous" motion is a myth, just that we couldn't know if two otherwise identical particles were somehow swapping places.

If you start with two identical billiard balls $A$ and $B$ out in space, which we will take to be our particles, everything you say would hold. Even though the motions of these balls are governed by Newton's laws, how could you really "know" if these two balls were discreetly and unobservably swapping places?

If you simply wrote the letters 'A' and 'B' on them separately, this ambiguity would be resolved, because now the billiard balls are not the same. The philosophical question at this point is thus: in the case where you don't distinguish them by writing letters on them, does that fact that you **could** do this mean that they really are distinguishable?

As far as the rectilinear paths of two billiard balls are concerned, this question has absolutely no physical significance. The field of physics where this does have profound significance is statistical mechanics, where one must count the number of physically equivalent microstates of a system.

What you've stated in the case of an ideal gas leads to the well-known [Gibbs paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_paradox). If you assume that in an ideal gas, the point-particles should be distinguishable (as per the philosophical question before), you will derive an equation for entropy that is not extensive.

$$S = Nk_B \ln (V) + N f(T)$$

where $f$ is some function. This means that if $N$ and $V$ are multiplied by a common factor, $S$ doesn't scale equivalently, as it should according to classical thermodynamics. This isn't exactly an issue, since [entropy is an anthropomorphic concept](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.01967#:%7E:text=According%20to%20E.T.,variables%20and%20calculating%20entropy%20differently.), but it means the entropy needs to be amended artificially to give the extensive entropy which we know from thermodynamics.

Gibbs noticed that if you instead make the assumption that the particles are indistinguishable (i.e. permuting any of the identical particles leads to an equivalent physical state), the entropy will change to:

$$S = Nk_B \ln \left( \frac{V}{N}\right) + N f(T)$$

which solves the issue, and gives the familiar entropy. This would suggest that particles in an ideal gas are truly indistinguishable, as you suggested in your post, which confused many people at that time. The ultimate resolution came from quantum mechanics and quantum statistics.

Comment: Thank you. In the last part of your answer you mention that "the ultimate resolution came from quantum mechanics and quantum statistics." The original motivation for this question was purely mathematical and concerned functions from $\Bbb R$ to an arbitrary metric vector space, subject to certain constraints. This is why I assumed it doesn't matter if we trade position functions for wavefunctions, because we're still dealing with functions from $\Bbb R$ to a vector space. Could you explain the change in moving from the classical to the quantum case?

Comment: In QM particles are eigenstates of the underlying Hamiltonian. Two particles with identical quantum numbers (eigenvalues of mutually commuting operators which also commute with the Hamiltonian) are therefore literally identical, which justifies the resolution Gibbs suggested to his paradox.

Comment: It goes even further - in QM the interchange of two fermions leads to a flip in sign on the overall wavefunction, whereas for two bosons it does not. This leads to the Pauli exclusion principle, which says two fermions cannot occupy the same quantum state. So in a gas of fermions you must exclude counting states where more than 1 fermion occupies a given state, whereas any number of bosons can occupy a given state.

Comment: Ah, and since the Hailtonian is for the whole system we end up doing away with the indexed set of wavefunctions ($\{\psi_A,\psi_B\}$ in the example) altogether?

Comment: No you can continue to use the notation $|A,\{\lambda\}_1 \rangle $ and $|B,\{ \lambda\}_1 \rangle$, which denote the single-particle states where $A$ has quantum numbers $\{\lambda\}_2$ and similar for particle $B$. But in QM if particles $A$ and $B$ are not distinguishable by any possible measurement, i.e. they have the same quantum numbers $\{\lambda\}$, then they truly are identical and indistinguishable. The full wavefunction must therefore respect the symmetry of interchanging two particles.

Comment: However it may be possible that we think two particles are identical, but they actually posses an intrinsic property (such as spin, or color) which distinguishes them. For example, maybe $A$ and $B$ have the same quantum numbers $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$, and therefore we naively think they are identical, but there may be another quantum label $\lambda_4$ where they differ. This was essentially how [color-charge](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Color_charge) was first discovered.